# Is ColdFusion on Linux/Apache stable?

Tags: apache, coldfusion, railo, cfml

I'm working on a site that still has a lot of scripts in ColdFusion. I need to move it to a new server. I much prefer Apache/Linux instead of IIS/Windows. I've seen some info here and there about running ColdFusion on Apache/Linux. Is that a stable setup?

Comment: I also should add - Am I going to need to modify the scripts to accommodate the new type of server?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Check the first link I posted. Since Linux is case-sensitive, you may have some work ahead of you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely (32bit and 64bit) - you can see a list of officially supported platforms on the Adobe site:
http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/systemreqs/

Linux OS:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.3
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10.3
Ubuntu 9.04

Apache HTTP Server 2.0.63 and later

Answer (score 9):

It's perfectly stable. I ran a hosting company with ColdFusion 4 through 6.1 running first on Fedora and later CentOS. I used to work for Nationwide and deployed a major application there using ColdFusion 6.1 and later 7 of Red Hat ES.

I've written an extensive article on what you'll run into when [moving a ColdFusion application from Windows to Linux](http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/5/24/Moving-Coldfusion-applications-from-Windows-to-Linux).

You can find more info about running ColdFusion on Linux [here](http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/Linux) or by searching [ColdFusionBloggers.org](http://www.coldfusionbloggers.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I have had absolutely no problem ever running Coldfusion on Apache on linux.

In fact, I had a windows NT 3.51 server running Apache (for windows) beta for several years, with Coldfusion 4.5.  Zero issues.

The server still runs and I only turned it off because it was outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I have run Allaire, (no!!), Macromedia... (No!) Adobe Coldfusion on GNU/Linux since Debian Woody (2003), (usually on unsupported distros). It works fine, as long as you understand that you can't purchase support. I even clustered them, but the Apache connector can cause some angst.